# I am trying to build a program that saves unknow faces in a directory and print out "already exist" if the face already exist in the directory

Tags: python

**Updated code**

Error:

return face_detector(img, number_of_times_to_upsample) TypeError: **call**(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (self: dlib.fhog_object_detector, image: array, upsample_num_times: int=0) -> dlib.rectangles Invoked with: <dlib.fhog_object_detector object at 0x0000020E3962CBF0>, [(10, 117, 46, 81)], 1

whenever a new face appears the program captured it and throws this type of error.it was supposed to run until I stop it.

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import glob

myPath = 'E:/Project_code/demo2'
   
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
known_face_encodings = []

i = len(glob.glob1(myPath,"*.jpg"))
count = i
temp=0

def known(temp):
    while temp<i:
        known_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file(str(temp) + ".jpg")
        known_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_picture)[0]
        known_face_encodings.append(known_face_encoding)
        temp = temp + 1

known(temp)

**This function is causing the error**

def new_known(rgb_small_frame):
    x=face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
    x_code = face_recognition.face_encodings(x)[0]
    known_face_encodings.append(x_code)
        
while True:
    process_this_frame = True
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video.read()

    # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    if process_this_frame:
            # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

            
            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                print(matches)
                if True in matches:
                    print("already exist")
                else:
                    cv2.imwrite(str(count) + '.jpg',frame)
                    new_known(rgb_small_frame)
                    count = count + 1
                    break
    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `if whatever_expression == True:` almost always should be just `if whatever_expression:`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the image every time you compare with some image in the directory, and every loop you are updating the `num` which makes your loop infinite.

```
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    if True:
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
        my_new_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame,face_locations)
        result = False
        i = 0
        while not result:
            i += 1   
            unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file(str(i) + ".jpg")
            unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)[0]
            
            result = face_recognition.compare_faces(my_new_encoding, unknown_face_encoding)
        if result:
            print("Already Exist")
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(str(i) + '.jpg',frame)
            num = num+1
```

Comment: where do i use the innitialize and increment the value of 'i'?
unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file(str(i) + ".jpg")

Comment: Updated the initialization and incrementing of `i`.

Comment: Having this types of error, any solution:
return face_detector(img, number_of_times_to_upsample)

TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: dlib.fhog_object_detector, image: array, upsample_num_times: int=0) -> dlib.rectangles

Invoked with: <dlib.fhog_object_detector object at 0x0000020E3962CBF0>, [(10, 117, 46, 81)], 1

Comment: Newly added a function which is causing the problem:
def new_known(rgb_small_frame):
    x=face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
    x_code = face_recognition.face_encodings(x)[0]
    known_face_encodings.append(x_code)

Comment: Main method:
for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                print(matches)
                if True in matches:
                    print("already exist")
                else:
                    cv2.imwrite(str(count) + '.jpg',frame)
                    new_known(rgb_small_frame)
                    count = count + 1
                    break

Comment: It is not possible to check and fix all the error you get because of other parts of program, since you had shared only one loop which you wanted to fix.

Comment: I updated the post with full code and the error, it will be great help if u show me the problem of my code.